# Prove increasing convex function has increasing differences

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $v: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be an increasing, convex function.

For any $t>0$ I want to show that for all $x_{1} \leq x_{2}$ we have: $$v(x_{1}+t) - v(x_{1}) \leq v(x_{2} +t) - v(x_{2})$$

This of course can be illustrated heuristically if $v$ is twice differentiable. But I am trying to show this from the definition of a convex function and by the fact that $v$ is increasing, but I am just moving in circles. I am pretty sure this result is true, and I need it to finish a proof I am working on.

Any suggestions will help.

Comment: Hello, I was considering a similar question. Does this imply that the second derivative of $v$ is increasing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $x_1 \le x_1+t,x_2 \le x_2+t$, from the definition of convexity we have
$$ v(x_1+t) \le \left(\frac{x_2-x_1}{x_2-x_1+t}\right)v(x_1) + \left(\frac{t}{x_2-x_1+t}\right)v(x_2+t) $$
and
$$ v(x_2) \le \left(\frac{t}{x_2-x_1+t}\right)v(x_1) + \left(\frac{x_2-x_1}{x_2-x_1+t}\right)v(x_2+t).$$
Adding up the inequalities gives the desired inequality.

Comment: I think this is a great and succinct answer. However, before I accept and upvote, I am wondering if you can explain the steps you took to get to this solution? I worked for a while on this problem and could not get here, so I want to understand how you reached this point.

Comment: Nevermind, I see the logic. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm sorry, i made mistake for edit. Original answer is also correct. It is good answer.

Answer (score 2):

[This inequality is true for any convex function, increasing or not.]

I'm going to assume that $x_2\le  x_1+t$. The reasoning in the remaining case is similar. First consider the three points $x_1\le x_2\le x_1+t$. We have
$$
x_2={x_1+t-x_2\over t}x_1+{x_2-x_1\over t}(x_1+t),
$$
so by the convexity inequality for $\nu$,
$$
\nu(x_2)\le {x_1+t-x_2\over t}\nu(x_1)+{x_2-x_1\over t}\nu(x_1+t).
$$
Similarly,
$$
\nu(x_1+t)\le {x_2-x_1\over t}\nu(x_2)+{x_1-x_2+t\over t}\nu(x_2+t).
$$
Now add these two inequalities, clear $t$ from the denominator, and simplify.